# Publishing Container (external access)

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I started a nginx container, I can access it through the local ip (192.168.0.1).

I want to externally access mysite.dns.net

I did the port redirection on the router, but it didn’t work.

access 192.168.0.1:8080 work
access mysite.dns.net:8080 didn’t work

Note: Use linux VM.